# Laravel get unamed "GET" parameter id from URL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, url-parameters, get-request

I am trying to get a value from the url that looks more or less like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/new-user/7
```

This number 7 passed in the url as a parameters is an ID in which i submit from the blade form as a request for an action i perform in the controller but i cant get this value in anyway. 
This is what i tried so far:

I tried to use this in the controller in which i submitted the form

```
$request->route('company_id');
```

I also tried to get this as a proper GET parameter:

```
<input type="hidden" name="company_id" id="company_id" value="{{app('request')->input('company_id')}}">
```

and i also tried this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="company_id" id="company_id" value="{{Input::get('company_id')}}">
```

and this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="company_id" id="company_id" value="{{$_GET['company_id']}}">
```

None os these options work and i still receive an empty value.

Any ideas or suggestions on how can i get this variable?

Thank you!

Comment: Can I see your route please

Comment: @Andres Hernandez:Route::get('/new-user/{company_id}', ['as'=>'new-user','uses'=>'UserController@newUserView']);

Comment: how are you getting the parameter in controller?, can you add that part clearly?

Comment: This id is in the URL and on this same page's blade content, i expect to get this id from the url and pass as a hidden input field through the form submission ($request->input('company_id')). Then in the controller i handle variable

Comment: if you are able to get it from controller function that displays the form, then just pass it to the form from that function ?

Comment: No man, this is the questions, i am not able to get it form the return view controller, this is coming from an email link as a route parameter. Is there any way to get straight from the url?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A [route parameter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-parameters) and a [query parameter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#retrieving-input) are two different things.

If you have a route defined like this:

```
/** routes/web.php */

Route::get('/new-user/{id}', 'UsersController@show');
```

In this case `$id` is a route parameter. So to get in your blade view you could do:

```
/** resources/my_view.blade.php */

{{ request()->id }}
```

So, with a request like the one you used `http://localhost:8000/new-user/7` that should output: `7`.

Another case is when you have a [query param](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#retrieving-input). These variables doens't need to be defined in the route. For example a call of this type, using the same route defined in the previous example:

```html
GET http://localhost:8000/new-user/7?foo=bar
                                    ^^^^^^^^
```

In this case the `foo=bar` can be accessed like this:

```
{{ request()->query('foo') }} // 'bar'
```